# How to add newlines into variables in bash script

Tags: bash, quoting

When I do

```
str="Hello World\n===========\n"
```

I get the `\n` printed out too. How can I have newlines then?

Comment: While the answers here are great, in reality I think you'd be better off using an array for this sort of thing most of the time.

Comment: See also the question [Trying to embed newline in a variable in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139401/trying-to-embed-newline-in-a-variable-in-bash).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In `bash` you can use the syntax

```
str=$'Hello World\n===========\n'
```

Single quotes preceded by a `$` is a new syntax that allows to insert escape sequences in strings.

Also `printf` builtin allows to save the resulting output to a variable

```
printf -v str 'Hello World\n===========\n'
```

Both solutions do not require a subshell.

If in the following you need to print the string, you should use double quotes, like in the following example:

```
echo "$str"
```

because when you print the string without quotes, newline are converted to spaces.

Comment: What is the syntax `str=$'Hello World\n===========\n'` called? variable substitution?

Comment: @zengr: It's called [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), and it's also supported in `zsh` and `ksh`; however, it is NOT POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @mkelement0, it comes from ksh93, is also supported by zsh, bash, mksh and FreeBSD sh, and its inclusion in the next major revision of POSIX is [under discussion](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with double quotes? e.g. `str=$"My $PET eats:\n$PET food"` ? [This approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106456/22734) works for double quotes

Answer (score 41):

You can put literal newlines within single quotes (in any Bourne/POSIX-style shell).

```
str='Hello World
===========
'
```

For a multiline string, [here documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) are often convenient. The string is fed as input to a command.

```
mycommand <<'EOF'
Hello World
===========
EOF
```

If you want to store the string in a variable, use the `cat` command in a command substitution. The newline character(s) at the end of the string will be stripped by the command substitution. If you want to retain the final newlines, put a stopper at the end and strip it away afterward. In POSIX-compliant shells, you can write `str=$(cat <<'EOF'); str=${str%a}` followed by the heredoc proper, but bash requires the heredoc to appear before the closing parenthesis.

```
str=$(cat <<'EOF'
Hello World
===========
a
EOF
); str=${str%a}
```

In ksh, bash and zsh, you can use the `$'…'` quoted form to expand backslash escapes inside the quotes.

```
str=$'Hello World\n===========\n'
```

Comment: I'm using GNU bash 4.1.5, and `str=$(cat <<'EOF')` doesn't work as-is.. The `)` needs to be placed on the next line after the end-of-doc `EOF`.. but even so, it loses the trailing newline due to Command Substitution.

Comment: @fred Good points, I've explained about the trailing newlines and shown code that works in bash. I think it's a bug in bash, though to be honest upon rereading the POSIX spec I find it unclear that the behavior is mandated when the << is inside a command substitution and the heredoc isn't.

Comment: Great stuff; to preserve trailing (and leading) `\n` instances in `bash` when capturing a here-doc in a variable, consider `IFS= read -r -d '' str <<'EOF'...` as an alternative to the stopper approach (see my answer).

Comment: The very first example doesn't work in my bash. It results in `str=Hello World`

Comment: @mblakesley It does work. You've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Ugh, you're right, I was checking it wrong! I was checking with `env | grep <var>`, which of course only showed the first line ‍♂️. Thank you for following up!

Answer (score 27):

If you need newlines in your script many times you could declare a global variable holding a newline. That way you can use it in double-quoted strings (variable expansions).

```
NL=$'\n'
str="Hello World${NL} and here is a variable $PATH ===========${NL}"
```

Comment: Why would `$''` require a subshell?

Comment: Sorry, I misread an answer.

Comment: Could I ask for explanation from downvoters?

Comment: Nice! This can be included in variables using double quotes, e.g. `"My dog eats:${NL}dog food"`

Comment: This worked for me. When using a bash script to composite a string that gets automatically copied onto the clipboard for subsequent pasting elsewhere, this approach worked for adding newlines in the resulting output.

Comment: @Mat I believe the subshell is there so that `\n` gets evaluated into a linefeed. That way, when it's inserted into the string, depending on where/how the string is used, the linefeed is no longer interpreted as a string literal.

Answer (score 13):

Are you using "echo"? Try "echo -e".

```
echo -e "Hello World\n===========\n"
```

Comment: BTW. You don't need the final \n, because `echo` will automatically add one, unless you specify -n. (However, the main brunt of the question, is how to get these newlines into a variable).

Comment: +1 Of all the solutions, this one is the most direct and simplest.

Comment: echo -e doesn't work in OS X

Comment: @GregKrsak: In `bash`, `echo -e` _does_ work on OS X - that's because `echo` is a bash _builtin_ (rather than an external executable) and that builtin does support `-e`. (As a builtin, it should work on _all_ platforms that bash runs on; incidentally, `echo -e` works in `ksh` and `zsh` too). By contrast, however, the _external `echo` utility_  on OS X - `/bin/echo` - indeed does _not_ support `-e`.

Answer (score 8):

From all discussion, here is the simplest way for me:

```
bash$ str="Hello World
==========="
bash$ echo "$str"
Hello World
===========
```

The **echo** command must use **double quotes**.

Comment: nice .. except when there are double quotes inside the string..

Comment: you must escape double quotes with `\"`

Comment: That's often not really possible. I use triple quoted strings which work great.

Answer (score 7):

To complement the great existing answers:

If you're using `bash` and you prefer **using actual newlines for readability**, **`read`** is another option for **capturing a here-doc in a variable**, which (like other solutions here) doesn't require use of a subshell.

```
# Reads a here-doc, trimming leading and trailing whitespace.
# Use `IFS= read ...` to preserve it (the trailing \n, here).
read -r -d '' str <<'EOF'   # Use `IFS= read ...` to preserve the trailing \n
Hello World
===========
EOF
```

```
# Test: output the variable enclosed in "[...]", to show the value's boundaries.
$ echo "$str"
[Hello World
===========]
```

- `-r` ensures that `read` doesn't interpret the input (by default, it would treat backslashes special, but that is rarely needed).
- `-d ''` sets the "record" delimiter to an empty string, causing `read` to read the *entire* input at once (instead of just a single line).

Note that by leaving `$IFS` (the internal field separator) at its default, `$' \t\n'` (a space, a tab, a newline), any *leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed* from the value assigned to `$str`, which includes the here-doc's trailing newline.
(Note that even though the here-doc's body starts on the line *after* the start delimiter (`'EOF'` here), it does *not* contain a *leading* newline).

Usually, this is the desired behavior, but if you do want that trailing newline, use `IFS= read -r -d ''` instead of just `read -r -d ''`, but note that *any* leading and trailing whitespace is then preserved.
(Note that prepending `IFS=`  directly to the `read` command means that the assignment is in effect during that command only, so there is no need to restore the previous value.)

---

Using a here-doc also allows you to **optionally use indentation** to set off the multiline string for readability:

```
# Caveat: indentation must be actual *tab* characters - spaces won't work.
read -r -d '' str <<-'EOF' # NOTE: Only works if the indentation uses actual tab (\t) chars.
    Hello World
    ===========
EOF
```

```
# Output the variable enclosed in "[...]", to show the value's boundaries.
# Note how the leading tabs were stripped.
$ echo "$str"
[Hello World
===========]
```

Placing `-` between `<<` and the opening here-doc delimiter (`'EOF'`, here) causes leading tab characters to be stripped from the here-doc body and even the closing delimiter,
but do note that this **only works with *actual* tab characters**, not spaces,  so if your editor translates tab keypresses into spaces, extra work is needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

result=""

foo="FOO"
bar="BAR"

result+=$(printf '%s' "$foo")$'\n'
result+=$(printf '%s' "$bar")$'\n'

echo "$result"
printf '%s' "$result"
```

output:

```
FOO
BAR

FOO
BAR
```

Comment: Why not simply `result+=$foo$'\n'`? `$(printf %s "$foo")` would trim the trailing newline characters in `$foo` if any.

Comment: There is no explanation for the code, else it looks fine to me.

Comment: This makes sense when the `printf` format is more complex than just `'%s'`. It's the best way I've seen so far to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first comment on the question mentions arrays, but nobody shows how to do it with arrays, so here it is.

```
str=( "Hello World" )
str+=(===========)
printf '%s\n' "${str[@]}"
```

The first line creates an array with one element. Here the quotes are necessary (single quotes work too), otherwise the two words would be added as two separate array elements.

The second line adds one more element to the array with the `+=` operator. Here the quotes are optional, because there is no whitespace.

The third line prints out each array element as string (`%s`) followed by a newline (`\n`).

There can be whitespace around the array elements, on the first line I added spaces between the string and brackets, on the second I omitted spaces, to show it works both ways.

Answer (score -2):

you need to do it this way:

```
STR=$(echo -ne "Hello World\n===========\n")
```

**Update:**

As Fred pointed it out, this way you will loose trailing "\n".
To assign variable with backslash sequences expanded, do:

```
STR=$'Hello World\n===========\n\n'
```

let's test it:

```
echo "[[$STR]]"
```

gives us now:

```
[[Hello World
===========

]]
```

Note, that $'' is different than $"". The second does translation according to current locale. For deital see QUOTING section in `man bash`.