# How to correctly store a newline character in a (POSIX) shell variable?

Tags: shell, posix, newlines

**update** attempt to clarify more, using an example, does the following shell commands:

```
SHELLVARIABLE="1st line,
2nd line,
3rd line,
" 
printf '%s' "$SHELLVARIABLE"
```

generate this output:

```
1st line,<newline>2nd line,<newline>3rd line,<newline>
```

`<newline>` being the character `0x0a` / `\n`?

**Original question formulation**

What is the correct (POSIX-confirm) way to store a **newline** character `0x0a` (aka known by its commen c style escap `\n`) into a shell variable.

I want to make sure that doing the following:

```
SHELLVARIABLE="
"
```

is, not merely working by chance but instead is indeed the correct way.

Since POSIX's [printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1p.html) is perfectly capable of producing a newline character (i.e. `printf '\n'`, or `printf '%b' '\0012'`) I first attempted a more explicit (? or correct?) form:

```
SHELLVARIABLE="$(printf '\n')"
```

though a tempting approach, does **not** work. As the according to [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), command substitution (i.e. via `$()` and `` ` ` ``) shall remove

> sequences of one or more *newline*s at the end of the substitution.

Note: Asking to store a single trailing newline into a shell variable is only to abstract the more general use case (i indeed seek answer to) that is how to store a string into POSIX shell variable which ends with the **newline** character.

Comment: Not absolutely sure I understand the Q, but you may find something useful at para 3.243 in [this document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html). As I read all of this, <newline> is defined IAW the convention defined for the output device.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/how-to-add-newlines-into-variables-in-bash-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a hard newline in a quoted string is fine.

Though personally, I'd avoid it if you just want the newline: I find it looks odd and there's a slight risk of accidentally hitting extra spaces at the end of the first line (so you'd get e.g. `<space><newline>`). But that's just me.

Command substitution indeed strips *trailing* newlines, but only those. The workaround is to make sure that the final character is something other than a newline and then strip that character off.

Both of these should give you a newline:

```
nl1='
'

nl2="$(printf '\nx')"
nl2="${nl2%x}"
```

Comment: I am happy to read your answer confirming that I can use indeed a "hard newline" (is that how it is referred, when occring verbatitm in a thring?). Also great to have the alternative more explicit, yet overly "boilerplate" solution. Thank you. I would like to accept your answer, do you happen to know where there is a document/ref/spec that defines your given options?

Comment: This works well but IMHO it's utterly ugly in shell scripts...